Задача из Яндекс Контест Python
Профессор математики Ерёменко разработал теорию, согласно которой реальных цивилизаций гораздо меньше, чем считают историки. В его теории есть основная цивилизация A про которую известна последовательнось из N исторических событий. Каждое событие обозначается числами от 1 до N, каждое число встречается ровно один раз. В i-й год в цивилизации происходило событие Ai
​
Кроме цивилизации A существовали также две ”ложные” цивилизации B и C, для них профессор Ерёменко также выписал случившиеся с ними исторические события, происходившие синхронно с событиями в цивилизации A. В i-й год в цивилизации B происходило событие Bi, а в цивилизации C — событие
Ci. Эти события также обозначены числами от 1 до N (однако для этих цивилизаций числа могут повторяться).
В теории профессора Ерёменко порядок событий не важен, главное чтобы у всёх трех цивилизаций
A, B и C множества событий совпадали. Помогите профессору Ерёменко вычеркнуть информацию за некоторые годы (т.е. удалить из последовательностей элементы Ai, Bi, Ci для некоторых i) так, чтобы множества событий стали совпадать. Чтобы сенсационность открытия профессора была выше, необходимо минимизировать количество вычеркнутых годов.
Формат ввода:
первая строка - N (1≤N≤100000) — количество событий для каждой из цивилизаций.
В следующих трёх строках задаются описания исторических событий.
Формат вывода:
Выведите одно число — минимальное количество лет, информацию о которых необходимо вычеркнуть.
Пример 1
Ввод:
N = 7 
A = {7 6 1 2 3 4 5}, 
B = {7 4 3 1 1 5 5}, 
C = {2 6 5 4 1 7 3}
Вывод: 4

Пример 2
Ввод:
N = 9 
A = {7 4 2 6 8 9 5 3 1}, 
B = {7 4 3 9 4 6 5 1 2}, 
C = {7 8 2 6 8 9 1 5 3}
Вывод: 2

Два тесто прошло, остальное пишет неверный код
links = []
with open("input.txt", encoding="UTF-8") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        links.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

N = int(links[0])
r = links[1:len(links)]
A, B, C = map(str, [''.join(i.split(' ')) for i in r])


def func(N, A, B, C):
    set_A, set_B, set_C = set(A), set(B), set(C)
    common_events = set_A & set_B & set_C

    filtered_A = []
    filtered_B = []
    filtered_C = []

    for i in range(N):
        if A[i] in common_events and B[i] in common_events and C[i] in common_events:
            filtered_A.append(A[i])
            filtered_B.append(B[i])
            filtered_C.append(C[i])

    itogo = set(filtered_A) & set(filtered_B) & set(filtered_C)
    item_itogo = N - len(itogo)
    return item_itogo

min_chislo = str(func(N, A, B, C))

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file_out:
    file_out.write(min_chislo)

В чём может быть проблема подскажите пожалуйста, голова совсем не соображается почему неверно

Опишите ваше решение словами.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, а смысл?

@Qwertiy, пытаюсь понять где ошибка. В коде или в голове?


item_itogo = N - len(itogo)


Это неправильно. Нельзя использовать N для вычисления ответа, поскольку мы не знаем, сколько различных лет было изначально.
{1,1,2,2}, {1,1,2,2}, {1,1,2,2} => 0
{1,1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2}, {3,3,3,3} => 3
{1,1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2}, {1,1,2,2} => 2


Насколько я понимаю, правильное решение такое:
len(set(a) | set(b) | set(c)) - len(set(a) & set(b) & set(c))


Я не совсем понимаю пример который вы привели
N = 4, A = {1,2,3,4}, B = {1,1,2,3}, C = {1,1,2,3} - ответ будет 2 исходя из условий задачи, код выдаёт 2
N = 4, A = {1,2,3,4}, B = {1,2,3,3}, C = {1,2,4,4} - ответ будет 2, код выдаёт тот же ответ.
Объясните пожалуйста, что вы имели ввиду под "ЭТО НЕПРАВИЛЬНО.", можете хотя бы дать подсказку почему не правильно или на что лучше обратить внимание?

@user21395927, кажется, я ошибся. Я думал, что надо вывести количество вычеркнутых событий, а не лет...

@user21395927, ответ исправлен.

@Qwertiy, не верю в ваш ответ. Он операется на решени ТС, в котором common_events не изменен. В то время как он меняется при вычёркивании столбцов. Я боюсь, тут нужен не просто цикл, но обход на подобие поиска по графу. Ещё соображение - ваше решение не зависит от состава столбцов вовсе. Это просто не возможно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, "порядок событий не важен, главное чтобы у всёх трех цивилизаций A, B и C множества событий совпадали" - не очень понимаю, что делать, если в год несколько событий...

@Qwertiy, вы удаляете столбец с событием A, которого нет в B или С. То есть получаете A1, B1, C1. И продолжаете этот процесс: Удаляте из A1 что-то чего нет в B1 или C1. Это циклический процесс. То какие будут получаться Ai, Bi и Ci зависит от состава столбцов. А ваше решение не зависит.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, для начала, что такое столбец? Сказано же, что порядок событий не важен.

Все события проиндексированы. Когда вы убираете "неудобные" события, вы из А удаляете Ai, из B - Bi,  из C - Ci. Все с одним и тем же индексом i. После удаления всех неудобных сбытий должно получиться set(A) == set(B) == set(C). В этом смысле порядок не важен.

"мы не знаем, сколько различных лет было изначально" - не так. Мы знаем что в A все события уникальны. То есть N = len(A).

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
